# jQuery isotope - change bricking sensibility

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Is there a way I can change the bricking sensibility? I'd like isotope to look further down the list and choose the best match.

Comment: If you don't need all the Isotope features then Packery, by the same author, does a better job of laying out items.